# How to convert code written in INNER JOIN to Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Need some help with converting code from Join statement into Subquery.
I need to remove GROUP BY from it somehow, when converted into Subquery and don't know how.
Managed to put small portion of subquery at the end of the code, don't know how to do rest.
Need some help, thank you.

Here is the sample of the code: (need to convert into SQL Server syntax)

```
SELECT 
     b.Number, t.IDTyre, SUM(c.Price)
FROM Tyre AS t
INNER JOIN Bill AS b ON t.BillID = b.IDBill
INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON c.TyreID = t.IDTyre
GROUP BY b.Number, t.IDTyre
HAVING SUM(c.Price) < 3000 OR t.IDTyre NOT IN (SELECT c.TyreID FROM Customer AS c)
```

Comment: As @Hardik mentioned, we need to know how you want the output to be displayed so we can make modification. In this sense, sharing some sample data and the expected output would be the best thing to do.

Comment: Which one is it? MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: This query doesn't make any sense. You are doing an inner join between c and t, but at the same time you are also looking for an "OR t.IDTyre NOT IN c.TyreID". These two statements are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Let me rephrase: either you don't need the OR clause, or you are trying to do something different. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below query works:

```
SELECT 
     (Select b.Number From Bill AS b Where b.IDBill = t.BillID) as Number,
     t.IDTyre as TyreID,
     (Select SUM(c.Price) From Customer AS c Having SUM(c.Price) < 3000 OR t.IDTyre NOT IN (SELECT Distinct c.TyreID FROM Customer AS c) And c.TyreID = t.IDTyre) as Price 
FROM Tyre AS t
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I'm getting some error saying:"An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to convert this to Sub Query?

JOINS are the best options while dealing with linking tables.

Also the "NOT IN" that you are trying to do at the end is also not good, you should use "NOT EXISTS". Change this to: OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Customer AS c WHERE t.IDTyre=c.TyreID)

Comment: I have some task that says to do it inevitable in subquery insted. Thank you for contribution.